# Powershell script to get more AD information from the script

Tags: powershell

I have a script that gets group name and member information, but I want it to also retrieve domain,groupname,type, description,distingushedname, managedby, members, fullname, username and display name. I have added a get-user command (the last line) but dont know how to incorporate it to the working part of the script.

`Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "Security" -and Name -like "*"}| %{
$Group = $_.Name
Get-ADGroupMember $Group | Select @{N="GroupName";E={$Group}},@{N="Member";E={$_.Name}}"
}| Export-Csv C:\Users\Desktop\AD\Report.csv -nti
Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties *  | select fullname*, username*, disp*,distinguishedName*,GroupName,GroupCategory,Member`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you need is:

- store entire group object in `$Group`
- pipe result of `Get-ADGroupMember` to `Get-ADUser`
- use `$Group` in `Select-Object` to add group properties to user properties.

Sample code:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * | ForEach-Object {
    $Group = $_
    Get-ADGroupMember $Group | 
        Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user'} | 
        Get-ADUser -Properties * | Select-Object FullName, SamAccountName, Disp*, DistinguishedName, @{
            Name = 'GroupName'
            Expression = { $Group.Name }
        }, @{
            Name = 'GroupCategory'
            Expression = { $Group.GroupCategory }
        }, @{
            Name = 'ManagedBy'
            Expression = { $Group.ManagedBy }
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you this does that i need, now i just need to add the ad domain command and all the information will be retrieved.